# My Update query over two tables doesn't work (MYSQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

*Database engine: MYSQL*

I'm having trouble with a SQL Update request. For some reason, I receive an error message, as soon as I execute my SQL (see further down). I have already adjusted my SQL command as some websites told me to (b.e [this one)](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-update-from-select-in-sql-server/).

Does someone know, what I did wrong? Thanks in advance.

**Query**

```
UPDATE user SET money = 20.00 FROM user Inner Join account on user.accountfk = account.accountID WHERE username = 'radol'
```

**Table user**
[image]

**Table account**

[image]

**Error Message**

[image]

**Desired Result**

I want to change the money value of the account table, by accessing through the username of the user table.

**What I have tried**

Of course i had a look on different website about INNER JOIN in combination with UPDATE. I adjusted my query exactly to the example on [this](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-update-from-select-in-sql-server/) website. But it didn't work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be your update statement:

```
update account a join user b on a.accountfk=b.accountid set money=20.00 where username='radol'
```

Comment: Thanks, the "a" and "b" confused me a little bit. Couldn't really tell what they meant. But your query got me to the right answer. In the end my query worked like this: 

update account join user on user.accountfk=account.accountid set money=20.00 where username='radol'

Comment: 'a' and 'b' referred as the Alias of table. It can be useful as a temporary name in the SQL query and for the readable purpose.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL specification for the `UPDATE` statement does not have `FROM` in its syntax.

[See here for further info.](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp)

This is also what the error message states:

```
"(...) Check the right syntax (...) to use near 'FROM user Inner Join account (...)
```

Please do not hesitate to leave a comment or shoot me a message if you need more guidance.

Comment: I had a feeling that the FROM is a little bit of place. Annoying that the website I had my information from, also had a FROM inside the Update query...

Answer (score 0):

you need to put alias for your tablename or mention username and money as user.money and user.username
Try this,
"UPDATE user INNER JOIN account ON user.accountfk = account.accountID SET user.money = 20.00 WHERE user.username = 'radol'";

Comment: I already figured it out with the help of Muhammad. But anyways your query worked perfectly fine as well. Except that you used "user.money" instead of "account.money"